# awk How to extract information from html tag

Tags: html, bash, awk

I want the FS to be <......>

the dots being ANYTHING. So if I have let's say

`<td width="50%" valign="top">System Hardware</td>`

I want to extract `System Hardware`. I've tried 2 things but it doesn't work.

1. `awk -F "\<([^>]+)\>" '{print $1}' test.txt`
2. `awk -F "\<?*\>" '{print $1}' test.txt`

In both cases I get nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting nothing because you're telling awk to print $1 which would be the field BEFORE the first field separator. You want `print $2`.

```
$ awk -F'<[^>]+>' '{print $2}' file
System Hardware
```